# Winpcap, DLL and open source

Tags: c, dll, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

I'm "trying" to study the Pcap library. Currently I'am using a Windows machine so I downloaded the Winpcap Dev pack. I would like to know the content of the function pcap_sendpacket. I searched the source files in the Winpcap Dev pack and only found the function in a header file, which doesn't contain the body of the function. I suspect the function is defined in the winpcap.dll file, but I can't find the source file for this DLL.

The question is, if the Winpcap project is opensource why the source code for all the files isn't published by the creators?

I mean, may be I am missing something, don't know, I am a newbie.

By the way, I found the function body in the libpcap library but this library is for linux not windows.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "I found the function body in the libpcap library but this library is for linux not windows".  No, libpcap is for many different UN\*Xes - see the different "pcap-XXX.c" files.  *Part* of WinPcap is also there, namely "pcap-win32.c", but that calls into the "Packet.dll" library, the source to which is in the WinPcap source.  Note that Packet.dll, in turn, makes system calls to a *device driver*, the source to which is also in the WinPcap source; that driver uses NDIS, the source to which is at Microsoft :-), but the APIs for which are documented.

Comment: Can you point in what file is this:

"Note that Packet.dll, in turn, makes system calls to a device driver"

And if you can recomend a book about all this thing of system calls and DLLs.

Thanks.

Comment: The source code for Packet.dll is in the `packetNtx\Dll` directory of the WinPcap source (or, if you're reading it on UN\*X rather than Windows, the `packetNtx/Dll` directory).  The source code for the driver is in the `packetNtx\driver` directory of the WinPcap source (or, if you're reading it on UN\*X rather than Windows, the `packetNtx/driver` directory).

Comment: What parts of "this thing of system calls and DLLs" do you want to know about?  And how familiar are you with Windows and with various UN\*Xes such as Linux?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know a book like "Linux System Programming" but for Windows?

Comment: I've never even heard of "Linux System Programming", so I don't know what a Windows equivalent would be, much less whether such an equivalent exists or, if it does, what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded 4.1beta5_WpcapSrc.zip from http://www.winpcap.org/archive/ and that appears to contain full source code. The function you refer to, `pcap_sendpacket` is defined in `wpcap\libpcap\pcap.c`.

Comment: This gets more confusing.

I downloaded this package:

http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpdPack_4_1_2.zip

which is very different with the one you posted. Now I don´t now what's the different between both packages.

In the pack I downloaded, if you see the pcap.c file, the function is not defined.

Comment: The WpdPack file is the developer's package; it includes what you need to develop software to use WinPcap, but it does *not* include the WinPcap source.  You want the WinPcap 4.1.3 *source code*, at http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/WpcapSrc_4_1_3.zip.